# Generators in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I have created a function to generate fibonacci series using es6 generators:

```js
//WARNING CAUSES INFINITE LOOP
function* fibonacci(limit = Infinity) {
  let current = 0
  let next = 1

  while (current < limit) {
    yield current
      [current, next] = [next, current + next]
  }
}

for (let n of fibonacci(200)) {
  console.log(n)
}
```

The above function doesn't swap the two numbers while if done normally in any other function swaps the two. On running this function I get an infinite loop.
Why doesn't the variable swap work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a syntax mistake: a missing semicolon makes the engine parse your statement as

```
yield (current [ current, next ] = [ next, current + next ])
//             ^        ^
// property access    comma operator
```

If you want to omit semicolons and [let them be automatically inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572) where ever <s>possible</s> needed, you will [need to put one at the *begin*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201206065632/http://inimino.org/%7Einimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) of every line that starts with `(`, `[`, `/`, `+`, `-` or `` ` ``:

```
function* fibonacci(limit = Infinity) {
  let current = 0
  let next = 1

  while (current < limit) {
    yield current
    ;[current, next] = [next, current + next]
  }
}

for (let n of fibonacci(200)) {
  console.log(n)
}
```

Comment: We should only allow people who understand ASI to omit semicolons :D

Answer (score -1):

You have to first swap and then yield.
Yield will give control back to the caller, so the method kindad stops executing there..

This will work (tested in Firefox

```
function* fibonacci(limit = Infinity) {
  let current = 0
  let next = 1

  while (current < limit) {
    [current, next] = [next, current + next];
    yield current;

  }
}

for (let n of fibonacci(200)) {
  console.log(n)
}
```